# Setting up Linode webserver

Tags: django, apache-2.2, web-hosting, linode

Hey guys I just got server space on linode and am trying to set up just a simple web hosting and backend for an iPhone app. I plan on using Django for all of it but have no experience in setting up the actual server.  I followed the linodes guides and helps for setting it up but must be missing something as I can't for the life of me get it working. I am trying to get the domain name mybuddybomb.com and edited the /etc/hosts as such:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
my.ip.add.ress   mrboom.mybuddybomb.com  mrboom
```

I have installed apache2 and am using ubuntu 11. I made a file called mybuddybomb.com in /etc/apache2/sites-available and added it to apache. it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost my.ip.add.ress:80>
 ServerAdmin myemail@domain.com
 ServerName mybuddybomb.com
 ServerAlias www.mybuddybomb.com
 DocumentRoot /srv/www/buddybomb/
 ErrorLog /srv/www/logs/buddybomb/error.log
 CustomLog /srv/www/logs/buddybomb/access.log combined
 PythonPath "['/srv/www/buddybomb/push'] + sys.path"
 WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/buddybomb/push/django.wsgi

<Location "/buddybomb/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE buddybomb.settings
    PythonOption django.root /buddybomb
    PythonDebug On
</Location>
```

I have installed all the python/django libraries required there is just something that i'm missing connecting everything.

I ran the command `apache2ctl -S` and that put out

```
 [error] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: Could not resolve host name mybuddybomb -- ignoring!
VirtualHost configuration:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80       is a NameVirtualHost
     default server mybuddybomb.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mybuddybomb.com:1)
     port 80 namevhost mybuddybomb.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mybuddybomb.com:1)
Syntax OK
```

Is there something I need to do in the linode console? or with apache? I have no experience in setting these things up and would really like some help setting it up.

The thing I'm confused about is I can enter the ip address in a browser and I know that apache is running and returns a page that the url isn't available but if I put www.mybuddybomb.com it says server not found. How do I connect the two?

Let me know if there is anymore info needed. I don't know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It doesn't look like you have buddybomb.com in your hosts. It should read

```
my.ip.add.ress    buddybomb.com www.buddybomb.com
```

`mrboom.buddybomb.com` isn't listed in your virtual host configuration.

2) Is `my.ip.add.ress` listed in the `NameVirtualHost` in your apache config? If so, you can just have `<VirtualHost *:80>`.

3) What address comes up when you do `host www.buddybomb.com`?

4) Is the `VirtualHost` clause of your config closed? I'm guessing yes since your configuration validates.